# Question about string splitting placed on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently just posted this: [Post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/216744/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-split-a-string) and it was flag as `primarily opinion-based`. The question is about methodologies. How is the question `primarily opinion-based`?

> I know there are many different kinds to ways to split a string, e.g.
>   you can use regex, `get_line` and strings internal functions, such as,
>   `find`, `find_first_of` and `find_last_of`. You could even loop
>   through a string character by character if you wanted to.
>
> What are some of the other ways you could split a string?

Comment: You need to check out [This Question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5882/how-to-get-rid-of-bullies-in-stack-exchange), Specially my answer. You'll get all the ideas you need.

Answer (score 5):

It's a polling question about what kinds of methodologies are out there. These kinds of [open ended questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) don't work well with the Stack Exchange format since every answer will be equally valid.